# Android: How do I get clipboard data?(Can't get clipboardmanager)

Tags: android, kotlin

Android official documentation on the topic of pasting says:

> Get the global ClipboardManager object using getSystemService(CLIPBOARD_SERVICE). Also declare a global variable to contain the pasted text:

```
var clipboard = getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE) as ClipboardManager
var pasteData: String = ""
```

When I do the exact same thing on my fragment, it tells me to create getSystemService function. Here's what I did:

My imports (I clicked import on everything Android Studio told me to):

```
import android.content.ClipboardManager
import android.content.Context
import android.content.Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.Button
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat.getSystemService
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import androidx.navigation.fragment.findNavController
import com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
```

My code:

```
class FirstFragment : Fragment() {
    var clipboard = getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE) as ClipboardManager
    var pasteData: String = ""

    override fun onCreateView(
            inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
            savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.pgn_page, container, false)
    }
    private fun pasteText():String {
        val abc = clipboard?.primaryClip
        val item = (abc?.getItemAt(0))
        return item?.text.toString()
    }
    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        //val pgnBar: TextInputEditText = view.findViewById(R.id.pgncode)
        val pgnBar: TextInputEditText = view.findViewById(R.id.pgncode)
        val clipButton: Button = view.findViewById(R.id.clipboardButton)
        pgnBar.setText(PGNCode.value)

        clipButton.setOnClickListener{
            pgnBar.setText(pasteText())
        }

        view.findViewById<Button>(R.id.startAnalysisButton).setOnClickListener {
            PGNCode.value = pgnBar.getText().toString()
            findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_FirstFragment_to_SecondFragment)
        }
    }
}
```

What should I change?

Answer (score 2):

`getSystemService()` is a method in `Context` and a `Fragment` is not a `Context`.

You can use `requireContext()` to access a fragment's context when it's attached to one. Fragment init phase is too early.

So add the context access and move the

```
var clipboard = requireContext().getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE) as ClipboardManager
```

to a function such as `pasteText()`.

Answer (score 1):

`getSystemService` is method in `Context`, use below inside a fragment

```
var clipboard = requireContext().getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE) as ClipboardManager
```